# Saying "mostly" in Japanese: ほとんど or something else?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, adverbs

I've come across a problem repeatedly when I use Japanese, and that is the proper use of ほとんど. I've gathered that it means *most* in an opposite manner; e.g. ほとんどない to say *mostly don't have* and I want to know how I can just say *most* in a regular manner; e.g. in *most people do that*.

For example, ほとんどの人 would be an incorrect translation of "most people"; is there a more correct way to phrase this, like たくさんの人 (which would mean a slightly different thing than I am aiming for; i.e. *a lot of people* instead of *most people*) or some other phrase that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ほとんどの人 seems to be a good translation of "most people".
[An example from NHK news](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012471891000/k10012471891000.html)